# jQuery mobile swipe content only

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

So I used the jquery mobile ui to do a page, swipe left/right, now this dosen't work for me since I just want to swipe only the content, not the entery body of the page, I tried to use `data-role="content"` but It doesn't work anymore only with `data-role="page"` is it posibile to have that swipe animation, but only for the content?

I have some `<article>` and I want to swipe them left/right....but I don't want to swipe the header and other things..just the middle section.

And also to disable that stupid jquery mobile theme if posibile.

//Le

Code structure

```
<header data-role="header"> .... </header>
 <section>
  <!-- only this part I want to swipe, one article at a time -->
  <article data-role="page"> .....  </article>
  <article data-role="page"> .....  </article>
  <article data-role="page"> .....  </article>
  <article data-role="page"> .....  </article>
  <!-- only this part I want to swipe, one article at a time -->
</section>
<footer> ... </footer>

  $('article').bind("swipeleft", function(){
    var nextpage = $(this).next('article[data-role="page"]');
    // swipe using id of next page if exists
    if (nextpage.length > 0) {
      $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, {transition: "slide",
    reverse: false}, true, true);
    }

  });

  $('article').bind("swiperight", function(){
    var prevpage = $(this).prev('article[data-role="page"]');
    if (prevpage.length > 0) {
    $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {transition: "slide",
    reverse: true}, true, true);
    }

  });
```

Comment: Please post codes as well ..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can cheat here, there's a way you can change page in jQM but make it look like only content has been changed. It can be done if you place a **data-id="footer"** attribute in every header and every footer.

I have created a working jsFiddle example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/NV6Py/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Share QR</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>     
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />   
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <article data-role="page" id="article1">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
      <h1>Articles</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <p>Article 1</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
      <h1>Footer</h1>    
    </div>
  </article>

  <article data-role="page" id="article2">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
      <a href="#article1" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
      <h1>Articles</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <p>Article 2</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
      <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article data-role="page" id="article3">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
      <a href="#article1" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
      <h1>Articles</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <p>Article 3</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
      <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
  </article>

</body>
</html>
```

In case you want to prevent jQM page styling you can do it with  a help of a **data-enhance="false"** attribute, it must be placed in page/article container and initialized with a :

```
<script>
    $(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
        $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
    });
</script>
```

Also remember, **mobileinit** event must be initialized before jQM js is loaded.

I have also a working example of this : http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/5gXKj/, this is a same example like top one but without jQM page markup enhancement.

Comment: You the best give me a minute to test this out!

Comment: The only problem that I see on my iphone, when I swipe left, the text size decreases and increases like a snap...

Comment: And it goes multiple slides foward... I guess I need an unbind..but I don't know how..

Comment: Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/NV6Py/ , this should prevent multiple event binding. There are other method of multiple event binding prevention and you can find them in my other answer/article: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600

Comment: In order to prevent that `snap`to the right I needed `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>` works like a charm now, God bless you! I will accept it right now!

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to pin your fixed headers/footers in their position and then slide will move content only.

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="site-header"> My fixed-position header </div>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
    ...
    <a href="#pagetwo" data-transition="slide">Slide to Page Two</a>
    ...
</div> 

<div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">
    ...
    <a href="#pageone">Go to Page One</a>
    ...
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
#site-header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

See also: http://www.artandlogic.com/blog/2013/11/jquery-mobile-transitions-static-vs-dynamic-content-part-ii/